# Is there a Prettier equivalent for Visual Studio 2017? (Or a way to set up something similar)

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, prettier

I recently started a job at a company who's product is built in ASP.Net. In the past I've used the Prettier extension in VS Code with my teams to keep everyone's styles uniform. I've searched for some similar extension in the VS MarketPlace but I can't find anything remotely close.

I know I can set up an editor config file but it doesn't cover nearly the same level of options as having a shared lint file that everyone uses. I know I can change the text editor options under tools but that only updates my settings.

What I really want is to be able to have a few global lint/config files in the solution that will apply styles to a file on save so everyone's formatting is consistent. If anyone has experience setting up something similar your thoughts/experience would be tremendously helpful. Thanks!

Comment: You might look into StyleCopAnalyzers alongside editorconfig.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You can. It only works for JS, but you can find the installation instructions [here](https://github.com/madskristensen/JavaScriptPrettier).

(Taken from official [docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/editors.html#visual-studio))

For support with other languages, you can use [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.CodeCleanupOnSave) extension.